# get events from iTunes (via AppleScript?)

Tags: applescript, itunes

I am controlling iTunes (on OSX) via AppleScript and would like to know when the user changes things like volume or pauses a song. Any idea how to do that except for polling via AppleScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes sends out a system wide notification so applications can be notified when there's a change. Cocoa applications can register to receive this notification, but standard applescript can't. As such your best bet would be to develop your application in Xcode using ApplescriptObjC or objective-c.

FYI: if you get that far the notification is called "com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" and you get it from the NSDistributedNotificationCenter.

So basically your only option is to poll iTunes from applescript.